# Find duplicates in column x, then remove row that has lower value in column y

Tags: r

I have single observations for some and double observations for others. In the case of double observations in x, I want to choose the row with the lower y value to remove that row.

`ex <- data.frame('x'= c(1:5, 1:3,5:6), 'y'= c(70,73,72,49,60,14,50,46,13,29))`

Original df: [image]

Desired result:
[image]

Comment: `ex %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  slice(which.max(y))` in `dplyr`

Comment: Thank you, but this seems to remove any other columns. What if I have another column z that I want to keep in this process?

Comment: No, it does not. Did you try it? `ex <- data.frame('x'= c(1:5, 1:3,5:6), 'y'= c(70,73,72,49,60,14,50,46,13,29), z = 1:10)` and `ex %>% group_by(x) %>% slice(which.max(y))`

Comment: You are right. I get a warning about implicit NAs but seems to have worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` to *find the largest number per group*:

```
aggregate(y ~ x, ex, max)
#  x  y
#1 1 70
#2 2 73
#3 3 72
#4 4 49
#5 5 60
#6 6 29
```